# Can bacnet4j work in android

Tags: android, bacnet, bacnet4j

I want to make a `BACnet` client in an android tablet.

Is it possible to use `BACnet4J` in `Android`? If yes, is there a different jar file for `Android`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the same Jar file. I am using Backnet4j 3.2.2 for my application. It is good library.